# Looping until blank column

Tags: vba, excel

I am putting together some VBA code which i think needs a loop.  Loops are often my biggest weakness with VBA and I need some assistance.

I have a text file which i import into an excel spreadsheet.  The length of how many columns and rows and down will vary day to day.
For example today's file might have data in columns A - H, tomorrow it might be A : P.  Each typical row count will be around the 200 mark, so not to long.

In essence im trying to make one long list in column A from all the data spread over multiple columns.
Im looking for a loop that checks if the column has data in it, if it does it then copies the data into the bottom of the data in column A.
So for illustration purposes  say the data goes out to column G, it will copy B1, xl down, find the first empty row in A and paste, then do the same for C, stopping after column G.

I hope I’ve been clear when writing this.
Thanks in advance
Matt

Comment: You might want to consider a StackOverflow or Google search and you will find plenty of solutions: https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+last+column

Comment: Have you written any code we can help with?

Comment: Up until now, the columns were pretty fixed in length, so i my VBA didnt have a loop in it as it the code just copied all the data in B into the bottom of A, up until F, which was usually blank but not always.  I've been trying to google something that does something similar on various websites, truth be told i cant get my head around loops :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first want to loop over all columns. So a FOR loop from column B to LastColumn (which there is a function for.) Then you want to loop through all rows within that column to find the first empty row, and then substract one to arrive at the last column with data.

```
 If Cells(row,col) = "" Then
   LastRowCopy = row -1
```

Then you want to copy everything to A1, and keep track of the last row you posted in. So you want to have a variable that counts. Something like:

```
LastRowPaste = LastRowPaste + row
```

I could write the code for it, but perhaps you learn more by figuring it out yourself.

Edit: Also perhaps an interesting read on finding last rows and or columns is this: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm

Edit2: You could ofcourse also use the same for finding the last column as the  method I used for finding the last row. Then you just loop through the columns and see if:

```
If Cells(1, col) = "" Then
 LastCol = col -1
```

Edit3:

I wrote out the entire code:

```
Sub copypaste()

Dim LastRowCopy As String
Dim LastRowPaste As String
Dim LastCol As String
Dim col As Integer
Dim row As Integer

LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
LastRowCopy = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
LastRowPaste = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For row = 1 to LastRowPaste
    If Cells(row, 1) = "" Then
         LastRowPaste = row
         Exit For
    End if
Next row


For col = 2 To LastCol
       If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(col)) = 0 Then
            LastCol = col -1
       End If
Next col

For col = 2 To LastCol
    For row = 1 To LastRowCopy
        If Not Cells(row, col) = "" Then
            Cells(LastRowPaste, 1) = Cells(row, col)
            LastRowPaste = LastRowPaste + 1
        End If
    Next row
Next col


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Luuklag,  That pretty much covers it, apart from there will be data in column A, so rather than A1 it would be the bottom of it.  Thanks

Comment: The data will be in Cells(LastRowPaste,1)

Comment: I wrote the entire code. Let me know if it works, I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Hi Luuklag,  I maybe should have emphasised that F1 might be blank, but F2 might have data in it.  At the moment this code will make E the last column.  Thanks

Comment: Could I have isblank B2 XL DOWN looping through the columns and when it returns FALSE for the first time have that as my last column?

Comment: Is there a row that always has data in it, or does it vary for all rows and columns?

Comment: I changed it a bit more to increase the logic. Not sure about the () around columns though, let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Now I come to think of it, as you might have empty cells throughout your data, my script stops at the first empty row it finds, so I will edit that now.

Comment: It should now copy all cells that have values, skipping empty rows within the column.

Comment: Any row with A as the column will have data but not nothing past A.  So row 2 at B might be empty but row 3 might go until AC.  Thanks

Comment: try if the code that is in my answer right now works for you.

Comment: IF application.counta(range(columns(col),columns(col))) = 0 comes up with a syntax error

Comment: I was afraid of that. See if my edit fixed it. I also changed the FOR loops to start at column 2, as it would be stupid to copy from column 1 to column 1 ;) Forgot about that.

Comment: I've still got the same syntax error, the whole line comes up as red from the off

Comment: How stupid, a for loop without a Then and missing and end if. Updating now.

Comment: also tried it for myself, looks like it is working now.

Comment: One final bug i think.  Column B, is over-writing column A, rather than finding the bottom of data set and pasting.  Can you assist?

Comment: Sorry, I understood the question wrong then. I thought column A was going to contain everything from the other columns, not thinking that it already contained data. Will update my answer shortly.